# Optimize join query with SUM, Group By and ORDER By Clauses

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have the following database schema

```
keywords(id, keyword, lang) :( about 8M records)
topics(id, topic, lang) : ( about 2.6M records)
topic_keywords(topic_id, keyword_id, weight) : (200M records)
```

In a script, I have about 50-100 keywords with an additional field `keyword_score` and I want to retrieve the top 20 topics that corresponds to those keywords based on the following formula : `SUM(keyword_score * topic_weight)`

A solution I implemented currently in my script is :

- I create a temporary table as follow `temporary_keywords(keyword_id, keyword_score )`
- Insert all 50-100 keywords to it with their `keyword_score`
- Then execute the following query to retrieve topics

  ```
  SELECT topic_id,  SUM(weight * keyword_score) AS score
  FROM temporary_keywords
  JOIN topic_keywords USING keyword_id
  GROUP BY topic_id
  ORDER BY score DESC
  LIMIT 20
  ```

This solution works, but it takes in some cases up to 3 seconds to execute, which is too much for me.

I'm asking if there is a way to optimize this query? or should I redesign the data structure into a NoSQL database?

Any other solutions or ideas beyond what is listed above are most appreciated

**UPDATE (SHOW CREATE TABLE)**

```
CREATE TABLE `topic_keywords` (
  `topic_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `keyword_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `weight` float DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`topic_id`,`keyword_id`),
  KEY `keyword_id_idx` (`keyword_id`,`topic_id`,`weight`)
)

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temporary_keywords 
(   keyword_id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    keyword_score  DOUBLE 
)
```

**EXPLAIN QUERY**

```
+----+-------------+--------------------+------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+--------------------------------------+----------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table              | type | possible_keys        | key                  | key_len | ref                                  | rows     | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+--------------------+------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+--------------------------------------+----------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | temporary_keywords | ALL  | PRIMARY              | NULL                 | NULL    | NULL                                 |      100 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | topic_keywords     | ref  | keyword_id_idx       | keyword_id_idx       | 4       | topics.temporary_keywords.keyword_id | 10778853 | Using index                     |
+----+-------------+--------------------+------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+--------------------------------------+----------+---------------------------------+
```

Comment: Is `keyword_id` indexed (or the start of an index) in both tables?

Comment: You tagged this (understandably) with [mysql]. So, bear in mind that your present audience is biased.

Comment: Please provide SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables, as well as the results of the EXPLAIN. (But 200m records is quite a lot, so 3 seconds seems alright to me)

Comment: @Uueerdo I updated the question with show create table.

Comment: @Strawberry I will provide the result of EXPLAIN as well

Comment: It seems really odd that weight would be part of that composite index (although it probably makes very little difference to the execution time)

Comment: `keyword_id_idx` index was originally designed as cover index for other queries, that's why `weight` was part of it, I will remove it if it can help with the current query.

Comment: I don't think it will make any difference actually, but the EXPLAIN might reveal more.

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect, but uncaught, syntax.

```
JOIN topic_keywords USING keyword_id
```

-->

```
JOIN topic_keywords USING(keyword_id)
```

If that does not fix it, please provide `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...`